# Understanding stubs in testing Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

After reading this article on '[Antipatterns for Rails controllers](https://semaphoreapp.com/blog/2014/02/11/rails-testing-antipatterns-controllers.html)', I have a doubt related to stubs. The code is the following:

```
describe "GET show" do
  let(:user) { build_stubbed(User) }
  let(:report) { build_stubbed(Report) }

  before do
    User.stub(:find) { user }
    user.stub(:find_report) { report }
  end

  describe "GET show" do
    it "finds the user's report" do
      user.should_receive(:find_report) { report }

      get :show, :user_id => user.id, :id => report.id
    end
  ...
end
```

My question is...When we do the following:

```
User.stub(:find) { user }
user.stub(:find_report) { report }
```

I guess we are creating a stubbed method for both the User class and user object, and what is between the block are the parameters.

So, my concern is, where is this 'stub' method defined? I know build_stubbed is from FactoryGirl, but where is 'stub' defined?

And also, what is the following doing:

```
user.should_receive(:find_report) { report }
```

What is the `{ report }` doing?

Comment: What's "between" the block is the *return* value of the stubbed method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know build_stubbed is from FactoryGirl, but where is 'stub' defined?

The "stub" method here is added to every object by RSpec, see the docs here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames.

> What is the { report } doing?

This is documented above as well, but it's specifying that the stubbed method :find_report will return `report` which in this case refers to:

```
let(:report) { build_stubbed(Report) }
```

Comment: So this: ``user.should_receive(:find_report) { report }```is actually testing two things? First, that the user receives find_report method, and also that the method returns 'report'?

Comment: No, it's not setting an expectation of what will be returned, it's telling RSpec to _actually_ return `report` when `find_report` is called.

Comment: No, it specifies that calls to the stubbed :find_report return report.